# Any SEO impact after removing the current breadcrumbs available upon the website?

Tags: seo, website-design, breadcrumbs

I have a very old website where a lot of the niche main keywords covered through the breadcrumbs. Now we have recently revamp our whole product at new Tech Stack (React - Strapi).

Now, what's the best practice will be with below given two use cases -

**1.** Remove all the breadcrumbs to improve the UX (As suggested by Design Team).

**2.** Use the BreadcrumbList schema to preserve this for Crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the best solution could be to use the BreadcrumbList schema to preserve the breadcrumbs for search engine crawlers while also improving the UX. This way, you can have the benefits of both worlds - improved UX for users and preserved breadcrumb data for search engines are not incompatible.

By implementing the BreadcrumbList schema, you can provide structured data to search engines, which helps them understand the hierarchy of your website's pages and how they are related. This can help improve your website's visibility in search engine results pages (SERPs) and potentially improve click-through rates (CTRs) from search engine users.

However, it's important to ensure that the breadcrumbs are implemented properly using the schema markup and follow [Google's guidelines for structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/sd-policies). Additionally, it's recommended to test the implementation to make sure it's functioning as intended and not causing any issues with your website's performance or functionality.

ps. when it comes to ReactJS and AngularJS also keep in mind, there can be some crawling issues with Google, even if they say it's all good, make sure rendering takes place, this is an extra tip to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go in order_)

1. Weird designers who can't make and place breadcrumbs in a way that doesn't ruin the UX. I am surprised by such a message from the designers. As practice shows, on large sites, breadcrumbs only increase UX, but not vice versa.

On some big projects,
intermediate elements are even made in the form of a drop-down list for related categories, so that it would be easier for a person to navigate the site. From experience, I can say that this increases the perseverance of a person on the site by about 10 percent.

2. Recently, Google said that microdata is needed for those sites that have a mess with the structuring of data on the page.
   That is, BreadcrumbList micro-markup is optional, but desirable.

I'd leave bread crumbs if I were you. Think about where to place them and leave. On one of my projects, I placed them at the very bottom of the page and there were no problems with this.